# How to sort items in nested list in ascending order in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers in nested lists. I need to sort those in ascending order, while keeping it in nested lists. I guess regrouping them in new nested lists.

I have following function:

```
def sorting(n): 
    for i in n:
        for e in range(1, len(i)):
            key = i[1]
            j = e - 1
            while j >= 0 and key < i[j]:
                i[j + 1] = i[j]
                j -= 1
            i[j + 1] = key

    for i in range(len(n)):
        return(n)

n = [[6, 2], [9, 5], [3, 7], [1, 8]]
print(sorting(n))
```

But it does not sort the list correctly. I get this:

```
[[2, 6], [5, 9], [3, 7], [1, 8]]
```

But it should regroup the nested lists in the following way:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

How can I edit my code to make this work?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are all the nested lists the same length?

Comment: Yes, they are, all include two numbers

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are the sublists in the input always pairs? Should the sublists in the output always be pairs?

Comment: Yes, just as I included, the list passed to function and how it should look like after sorting

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this would be to flatten the list, sort it, and then reassemble into a list of pairs:

```
n = [[6, 2], [9, 5], [3, 7], [1, 8]]
# flatten list and sort
f = sorted(i for l in n for i in l)
# put it back together into nested pairs
n = [[v1, v2] for v1, v2 in zip(f[0::2], f[1::2])]
print(n)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you should first flatten the list, then sort, then re-pair:

```
n = [[6, 2], [9, 5], [2, 7], [1, 8]]
flatlist = [ x for pair in n for x in pair ]
flatlist.sort()
result = [ list(t) for t in zip (flatlist[0::2], flatlist[1::2]) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions offer good ways to do this problem.

Here is an [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) solution that flattens the list with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) using `flatten()`, sort the numbers with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), then uses `grouper()` to chunk the result into length 2 pairs, and finally converts the result to a list of lists with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

The `flatten()` and `grouper()` methods are from [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def flatten(list_of_lists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)

lst = [[6, 2], [9, 5], [3, 7], [1, 8]]

result = list(map(list, grouper(sorted(flatten(lst)), 2)))

print(result)
```

Another thing to point out is you don't need to copy these methods into your code. You can simply install the [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package with `pip install more-itertools`, import it, then start using the methods.

Here is what it would look like:

```
from more_itertools import grouper, flatten

lst = [[6, 2], [9, 5], [3, 7], [1, 8]]

result = list(map(list, grouper(sorted(flatten(lst)), 2)))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```